# algorithm design for job-worker distribution

Tags: algorithm

A group of people and a group of jobs is given as input. Any person can be assigned any job and a certain cost value is associated with this assignment, for instance depending on the duration of time that the pertinent person finishes the pertinent job. This cost hinges upon the person-job assignment. Propose a polynomial-time algorithm that assigns exactly one person to each job such that the maximum cost among the assignments (not the total cost!) is minimized.

can anyone guide me to how to begin solving this problem I have been at it for 3 hours and so far this is what I got bu i dont know if its right

Function MinimumCost

```
Pass in: array of jobs as jobArr, array of people as peopleArr
m <-- length(jobArr)
n <-- length(peopleArr)
call <-- sort(jobArr)
call <-- sort(peopleArr)
assignment  array of pairs for person-job pairs
i <-- 0
j <-- m-1
While j >= 0
    IF i == n Then
        i <-- 0
    EndIF 
    assignment[i]  pair of peopleArr[i] and jobArr[j]
    j <-- j – 1
    i <-- i – 1
End While
```

End Function

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [edit] your post.

Comment: I still do not understand the question. What is "the maximum cost among the assignments", and how can "assignment cost" be computed from the given input? The input to your code appears to be two arrays: what do they hold? The names of jobs and persons? Some kind of cost that must be maximized?